# Software for making Toshiba Qosmio Function & multimedia buttons work

Tags: windows-7, toshiba-laptop, function-keys

I've just had to do a fresh installation of Windows 7 Ultimate x64 on my Toshiba Qosmio F60 and I've lost the functionality of the multimedia buttons (Wifi, play/pause, mute, etc) and all the Fn options.

[This is the list of software available for my laptop](http://www.mytoshiba.com.au/support/notebooks/qosmio/f60/pqf65a-05e02w/download?os=25). Which one will give me back the Fn and multimedia buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Toshiba Value Added Package restores all additional functionality, such as Fn and multimedia keys.